# Proving that a Banach space is of finite dimension

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space with $\dim X\le \infty$. such that $X^*$ (the dual of $X$ ) is finite dimensional.

Then, show that $X$ is of finite dimensional too and $\dim X = \dim X^*$.

Note If wherenever we know that $X$ is of finite dimensision, it is easy using linear algebra tools to show that $\dim X=\dim X^*$.

Therefore the assumption here implies that $\dim X^*=\dim X^{**}$. Which clearly not what I want. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: You want to show X** is isomorphic to X

Comment: @Daniel yes that was precisely my intension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $X$ is embedded in $X^{**}$ which is finite dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Use the canonical injection:
$$\iota: X \to X^{**}: x \mapsto \mathrm{ev}_x.$$